# Is the Present Simple form suitable?

Tags: present-tense, grammaticality-in-context

> I think I may be allergic to shopping malls. I am not sure if my condition ___ officially by medical science but I am sure there are others who suffer as I do. All I have to do is walk inside one of these awful places and within minutes the artificial "day light" from a thousand "soft" lights begins to give me a headache.

The foregoing quote is taken from a student-book for EL. The task is to put the word “record” in a grammatically correct form. So, is it alright to fill in “is recorded” instead of “has been recorded” as it is in the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

> ... my condition **is recorded** officially ...
>
> ... my condition **has been recorded** officially ...

Still, this is just clumsy English.  "Is recorded by medical science" is barely idiomatic.  You could say that the condition, "is *recognized* by medical science," or, "is *documented* in medical journals," or some other variation, but much simpler is something like:

> I don't know if mine **is a recognized medical condition**

Comment: Thanks! I changed 'verb' to 'word', it's my fault. But are there any signs which point at the Present Perfect form as a preferable one?

Comment: @Aer I'll echo this answer in that I find **recorded** to be odd. My own preference would be to say **is recognized**. There is nothing to indicate which verb tense *should* be used. Either is fine, especially without more context.

Comment: @JasonBassford got it. But this is another question... It seems like the authors of this text might have missed something in semantics. Btw, I've added more context in the question.

Comment: *Matches* doesn't work neither semantically (matches what?) nor grammatically (\*matches... by medical science).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski  yes, you're right.  I've edited.

Comment: @Aer  I've edited the question.  It's difficult to say which answer is *definitively* correct when all of the possible choices are subtly *wrong*.